# H1B work visa sponsorship: once a company starts the process, should I stop applying elsewhere?

Tags: new-job, visa

There are some companies in IT industries which provide sponsorship for H1B USA work visa. I have 6+ years experience in IT and am applying for work.

Should I continue the interview process with all other companies that provide sponsorship even if I have been selected by one company and they have initiated the work visa process? Or should I stop applying once selected?

This process takes 8-9 month and I am unsure about my final selection in a visa interview held in the embassy. This is a lottery system. If I stick to one company and wait until their final visa process is complete. I could be losing an opportunity with another company and time as well.

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvotes? This is a very legit question for immigrants trying to apply for jobs aboard.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to stick with one employer, because this involves significant investment on their part.

I am aware of other visas that bring you into the US while you are on the job for a particular company.  H1Bs would normally lead to 'resident alien' status and perhaps eventually citizenship.  These others (I don't recall what they are) basically mean that the person with the visa works here on his (or her) own (cannot bring family), and is not in the pipeline for residency. There is a big issue between the US and Indian governments right now over wages - many of the people working here under these visas are not paid according to US norms for those skills, and the US Congress is proposing to mandate comparable wages.

[travel.state.gov](http://travel.state.gov/visa/temp/types/types_1275.html)

In general, you are complicating things by involving more people. This will probably reduce your changes of success.

Comment: `involving more people` Did you mean by companies those provide sponsorship?
and if I stick to one company and visa won't get approved i.e. 8-9 month with one employer would be wastage.